# Forward IP-address to server behind Turris Omnia

Tags: router

A few years ago I setup my Turris Omnia to forward an external IP-address to an internal server.

Unfortunately I have forgotten how (or maybe Turris Omnia changed the interface).

Answer (score 0):

Use LuCI.

Network > Interfaces > Devices > br_wan > Configure

Under Bridge ports: eth2 is already selected. Add lan4 (or another port).

Now eth2 is bridged to lan4.

Finally configure the server with the static IP address and plug it in lan4.